# Is there any way for getting a file contains "<?xml version='1.0'?>" 2 times

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter-3

I hit a service and I get the data like the following xml.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Properties>
    <Property>  
        <Prop_Class>Residential</Prop_Class>
        <Prop_RefId>Resads -  FHGS - 2034 - 160 - 067546</Prop_RefId>
        <Prop_CompanyGroup>ma</Prop_CompanyGroup>
        <Prop_CompanyName>Propertysvhavs</Prop_CompanyName>
        <Prop_Locality>30</Prop_Locality>
        <Prop_Address1>3 Bedroom houses</Prop_Address1>
        <Prop_Address2></Prop_Address2>
        <Prop_Address3>Clare Road</Prop_Address3>
        <Prop_Address4></Prop_Address4>
        <Prop_Eircode></Prop_Eircode>
        <Prop_Latitude>533.3498</Prop_Latitude >
        <Prop_Longitude>623.260300000000029</Prop_Longitude >
        <Prop_Status>A</Prop_Status> 
        <Prop_SaleOrRent>Sale</Prop_SaleOrRent>    
        <Prop_SaleType>For Sale</Prop_SaleType>         
        <Prop_Type>Residential   Apartment</Prop_Type>               
        <Prop_Bedrooms>1</Prop_Bedrooms>
        <Prop_Bathrooms>3</Prop_Bathrooms>
        <Prop_FullDescription></Prop_FullDescription> 
        <Prop_Price></Prop_Price>
        <Prop_PriceOption>m</Prop_PriceOption> 
        <Prop_ShowPrice>Y</Prop_ShowPrice>
        <Prop_Negotiator>Philip O'Reilly - Test </Prop_Negotiator>                              
        <Prop_EnergyRating>A2</Prop_EnergyRating>
        <Prop_EnergyRatingDetails>A2</Prop_EnergyRatingDetails>
    </Property>
</Properties>
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Images>
    <Image>
        <Prim_RefId>Resads -  FHGS - 2034 - 160 - 067546</Prim_RefId>
        <Prim_CompanyGroup>ma</Prim_CompanyGroup>
        <Prim_Type>PA</Prim_Type>
        <Prim_Filename>http://www.prhjsgdh.ie/uploads/web/286_3 bed dev.jpg</Prim_Filename>
        <Prim_Status>A</Prim_Status>
        <Prim_Class>Residential</Prim_Class>
    </Image>
    <Image>
        <Prim_RefId>Resads -  FHGS - 2034 - 160 - 067546</Prim_RefId>
        <Prim_CompanyGroup>ma</Prim_CompanyGroup>
        <Prim_Type>PA</Prim_Type>
        <Prim_Filename>http://www.hashjshd.ie/uploads/web/286_3bedsemi-2014.jpg</Prim_Filename>
        <Prim_Status>A</Prim_Status>
        <Prim_Class>Residential</Prim_Class>
    </Image>
    <Image>
        <Prim_RefId>Resads -  FHGS - 2034 - 160 - 067546</Prim_RefId>
        <Prim_CompanyGroup>ma</Prim_CompanyGroup>
        <Prim_Type>PA</Prim_Type>
        <Prim_Filename>http://www.asdbjhsdh.ie/uploads/web/286_3 bed dev.jpg</Prim_Filename>
        <Prim_Status>A</Prim_Status>
        <Prim_Class>Residential</Prim_Class>
    </Image>
</Images>
```

but this XML contains 2 `<?xml version='1.0'?>`. so that I cant get the file contents.

is there any way to get the file as XML?
or even is any way to split the file into number of occurences of `<?xml version='1.0'?>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of reading this directly with any of the XML processing libraries as it is an invalid XML document.  There are two ways I can think of to do this though.

The first involves manipulating the `<?xml ?>` tag to make it a normal tag and wrapping the whole document in a common tag (`<base>` in this case, but this is not important).  Then you can load the whole document and extract data as normal...

```
$data = str_replace(["<?", "?>"], ["<", "/>"], $data);
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<base>".$data."</base>");
foreach ( $xml->Properties->Property as $property ) {
    echo $property->Prop_RefId.PHP_EOL;
}
echo PHP_EOL;
foreach ( $xml->Images->Image as $image )   {
    echo $image->Prim_RefId.PHP_EOL;
}
echo PHP_EOL;
```

All you need to remember is that there is one level above the existing structure which is why I refer to `$xml->Properties->Property`.

The second is to split the document into it's parts.  Using `explode()` taking the `<?xml ?>` tag as the divider and then process each part as usual.  The down side of this is that if the declaration changes, then this will fail.  The advantage of this is that it would work the same if you were passed the original XML document.

```
$list = explode("<?xml version='1.0'?>", $data );
$xml = simplexml_load_string ( $list[1] );
foreach ( $xml->Property as $property ) {
    echo $property->Prop_RefId.PHP_EOL;
}
echo PHP_EOL;
$xml = simplexml_load_string ( $list[2] );
foreach ( $xml->Image as $image )   {
     echo $image->Prim_RefId.PHP_EOL;
}
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: since `explode` will remove delimiter from its output does it make sense to return "<?xml version='1.0'?>" back before passing to simplexml?

Comment: @skyboyer it may be good for completeness, but AFAIK it won't make any difference to the overall process.  This would also apply to mehod 1 which also doesn't have the xml tag in the resultant document if you wanted to have it.

Comment: As a variant on this, rather than turning the XML declaration into an element, you could turn it into a processing instruction by replacing `<?xml ` by `<?pseudo-xml ` where `pseudo-xml` is any name of your choice other than "XML" in upper or lower case.